# Example Spring integration DSL for JPA Inbound Channel adapter

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-integration, spring-dsl

I can't find a useful example for polling a JPA source for inbound data. I know how to do this in XML but can't figure out how do it in DSL.

In short what I want to do is periodically poll a JPA repository for records then put the records into a flow that will do the usual filtering/transforming/executing.

Kind regards

David Smith

Answer (score 3):

You are right: there is no yet JPA components support in the Spring Integration Java DSL. Feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT) (`JavaDSL` component) on the matter and we'll take care about this demand. Feel free to [contribute](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions/wiki/Contributor-Guidelines) as well!

Meanwhile I can help you to figure out how to do that without high-level API.

The `<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>` is based on the `JpaPollingChannelAdapter` and `JpaExecutor` objects (exactly them we will use for DSL API). You just must to configure `@Bean` for `JpaExecutor` and use it like this:

```
@Bean
public JpaExecutor jpaExecutor(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
     JpaExecutor jpaExecutor = new JpaExecutor(entityManagerFactory);
     jpaExecutor.setJpaQuery("from Foo");
     ....
     return jpaExecutor;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jpaFlow(JpaExecutor jpaExecutor) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(new JpaPollingChannelAdapter(jpaExecutor))
                      .split()
                      .transform()
       ....
}
```

Everything else will be done by framework as usual for existing DSL components API.

**UPDATE**

> How to provide auto-startup= property when creating JpaPollingChannelAdapter programmatically? Also, is it possible to get this bean and invoke .start(), .stop() using control-bus?

See, Gary's answer. The `Lifecycle` control is a responsibility of `Endpoint` in our case it is `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`. So, you should specify that second Lambda argument, configure the `.autoStartup()` and `.id()` there to be able to inject the `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` for your `JpaPollingChannelAdapter` and operate with it for your purpose. That `id` really can be used from `control-bus` to `start()/stop()` at runtime.

Yes, I agree `JpaPollingChannelAdapter` is unfortunate name for that class because it is really a `MessageSource` implementation.

Comment: How to provide `auto-startup=` property when creating `JpaPollingChannelAdapter` programmatically? Also, is it possible to get this bean and invoke `.start()`, `.stop()` using control-bus?

Comment: Please, see an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: @ArtemBilan - Is there any other repo where we can have basics of spring integration dsl with JPA stuff . could you please tell us ..

Comment: We have some code snippets in Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.M4/reference/html/jpa.html#configuring-with-the-java-dsl-2. Plus there are some tests in the project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-jpa/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/jpa/dsl/JpaTests.java

Answer (score 2):

Wire up a `JpaPollingChannelAdapter` as a `@Bean` and use

```
IntegrationFlows.from(jpaMessageSource(), 
                      c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1000)))
                .transform(...)
                ...
```

See the [DSL Reference](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference) for configuration options.

This one's near the top (with a different message source).